# How to position HTML bordered box in the centre

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place a fully responsive text box in the centre of the page inside of an image. I haven't had any trouble placing the text box on the image but for some reason I am having trouble centring the box. I have tried reviewed and looked over multiple tutorials and stack overflow answers but nothing has been helpful. I have tried both width: 50% and margins but neither have worked. Attached below is my code. Again, I am fully aware that there are multiple answers to this question but none seem to work. Thanks a lot for the help it is highly appreciated!

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>

.back {
    min-width: 100%;
}

.title {
    font-size: 90px;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -483px;
}

.square {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    border: 8px solid #686868;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 225px;
}

.square:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


</style>
</head>

<body>

<img src="orilliaback.jpg" class="back" height=500 />

<div class="title">Orillia, Ontario</div>

<div class="square">
    <div class="content">
        Welcome to Orillia!
    </div>    
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Again, thank you very much!

Comment: In short, you just want to center `.square`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-another-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add `margin:0 auto` to `.square` :

```
.square {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    border: 8px solid #686868;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 225px;
    margin: 0 auto;/*/<-------------Added/*/
}
```

**Full Code:**

```css
.back {
    min-width: 100%;
}

.title {
    font-size: 90px;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -483px;
}

.square {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    border: 8px solid #686868;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 225px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.square:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/cute-bunny-1600x900.jpg" class="back" height=500 />

<div class="title">Orillia, Ontario</div>

<div class="square">
    <div class="content">
        Welcome to Orillia!
    </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use flex-box ;)

More info: [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox)

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>

.back {
    min-width: 100%;
}

.title {
    font-size: 90px;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -483px;
}

.square {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    border: 8px solid #686868;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 225px;
}

.square:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

   display:flex;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-direction: column
}


</style>
</head>

<body>

<img src="orilliaback.jpg" class="back" height=500 />

<div class="title">Orillia, Ontario</div>

<div class="square">
    <div class="content">
        Welcome to Orillia!
    </div>    
</div>

</body>

</html>
```